# How to stay up-to-date on modern philosophy?

Tags: reference-request, learning-methods

It is rather difficult to decide what to read, what is obsolete, and so forth.

How does one stay up-to-date on modern philosophical thought? Are there journal apps which show new essays, articles, studies, etc.?

Comment: I'm not a philosopher.  One way would be to sneak into the sylabusses of prominent classes in well-regarded universities and see what the professors make their lower-division and also upper-division students read.  This would form a nice basis for entry into the field, without artificially selecting for whatever's most radical and most novel, which is what you get by following philosophy in the news.

Comment: There is a blog [Daily Nous](http://dailynous.com/), the [American Philosophical Association](https://www.apaonline.org) website also has one along with other resources. One can also peruse leading journals in the field of interest, for example Synthese for   philosophy of science.

Comment: I would suggest that modern philosophical thought is no different from ancient philosophical thought. Hence people still study Plato, Aristotle, Aquinas, Nagarjuna and so forth. Philosophical problems and the range of solutions on offer never change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps the ideal app is this philosophy stack exchange that we are currently using.

Although the people who participate here need not be professional philosophers they do provide some insight and the content is focused around questions and answers rather than forum-style discussions. By actively participating one can stay motivated to continue learning. Search for topics using the available tags.

Here are questions that I have asked the professional philosophers on this site:

- [What are the top professional organizations that philosophers belong to?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/52946/29944)
- [What are the main reference tools professional philosophers use to do research?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/52984/29944)

Here are some useful online encyclopedias (listed in order of my perception of difficulty):

- [Wikipedia](https://www.wikipedia.org/)
- [Internet Encyclopedia of Philosophy](https://www.iep.utm.edu/)
- [Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy](https://plato.stanford.edu/)

Here are places to get books some of which are free:

- [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/)
- [JSTOR](https://www.jstor.org/) (for journal articles)
- [Project Gutenberg](https://www.gutenberg.org/)
- [Wikisource](https://wikisource.org/wiki/Main_Page)

I am hoping others will mention resources I am unaware of.